# ionic cannot open url in browser within http request

Tags: http, ionic-framework

i'm unable to open a link using window.open whithin a http request.
Here is how i tried:

```
     const config = {
      headers: {token: this.apiKey, authtoken: token},
    };
    const url = `https://api.eatsmartapp.de/delivery/users/receipt?id=${this.orderId}`;
    // @ts-ignore
    this.http.get<any>(url, config).subscribe(dataset => {
      window.open('link', '_blank');

    }, error => {

    });
```

If i try to open the link outside the subscription area its working fine but if i try to open it in my subscription, nothing is happening on my mobile device

Comment: What framework? Angular, Vue, React, Vanilla JS?

Comment: i'm using angular @Kinglish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `window` as a service. In your module.ts file

```
providers: [
    { provide: Window, useValue: window }
]
```

Then in your component.ts, or wherever

```
constructor(private window: Window) {
    // ...
}
```

in which case your window.open would be like

```
this.http.get<any>(url, config).subscribe(dataset => {
      this.window.open(dataset.url, '_blank');

    }
```